# millis() Not Resetting Properly in rolling() Method in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm working on a game in Processing and facing an issue where millis() is not resetting as expected in my rolling() method within the Player class. The method is triggered by pressing the down arrow, and it's supposed to reset the rolling timer. However, the values of roll and rollingTimer are not updating correctly. The stamina += 3 line in the same method works fine, indicating that the method is executing. I've added println statements for debugging, which suggest the issue is around the millis() reset. Here's the relevant portion of my code:
below are the relevant classes of my code

```
class King extends Character{
  float sideBlock;
  float attackBuffer;
  boolean miss;
  float attackTimerEnd;
  float elementBlock;
  float deathTimer;
  float animationTimer;
  float blockTimer;
  float missTimer;
  
  King(PVector pos, int health, float attackTimer, int damage){
    super(pos, health, attackTimer, damage);
    sideBlock = 0;
    MAX_HEALTH = 10;
    attackTimer = millis();
    attackBuffer = -1;
    miss = false;
    attackTimerEnd = 10000;
    deathTimer = -1;;
    activeKingImg = kingDefault;
    blockTimer = -1;
    missTimer = -1;
  }
  
  void drawMe(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    scale(3,3);
    if (activeKingImg != null) {
        image(activeKingImg, 0, 0);
    }
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  void death(){
    attackTimer = millis();
    knight.health = 10;
    gameState = LEVEL_TWO;
  }
  
  void drawDeath(){
    activeKingImg = kingDeathAnimation;
  }
  
  void attackingAnimation(){
    activeKingImg = kingAttack;
    animationTimer = millis();
  }
  
  void displayMiss(){
    if (millis() - missTimer < 500){
    translate(pos.x + 50, pos.y-100);
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("Miss!", width/4, width/3);
    }
  }
  
  void displayBlocked(){
    if (millis() - blockTimer < 500){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x + 50, pos.y-100);
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill(0);
    textSize(50);
    text("Blocked!", width/4, width/3);
    popMatrix();
    }
  }
  
  void nullifyLeft(){
   if (sideBlock < 1 && health >= 0 && millis() - animationTimer > 1100){
   pushMatrix();
   translate(pos.x,pos.y);
   activeKingImg = kingLeftBlock;
   popMatrix();
   }
 }
 
  void nullifyRight(){
   if (sideBlock >= 1 && health >= 0 && millis() - animationTimer > 1100){
   pushMatrix();
   translate(pos.x,pos.y);
   activeKingImg = kingRightBlock;
   popMatrix();
   }
 }
  
  void autoAttack(){
    if(health >= 0){
    if (millis() - attackTimer >= attackTimerEnd) {
    attackTimer = millis();
    attackBuffer = millis();

  }

  if (attackBuffer >= 0 && millis() - attackBuffer <= 1000) {
    if (millis() - knight.roll <= 500) {
      println("missing");
      miss = true;
      missTimer = millis();
    }
    attackingAnimation();
  }

  if (attackBuffer >= 0 && millis() - attackBuffer >= 1000) {
    println(miss);
    if (miss == false) {
      hit(knight,1);
      activeKingImg = kingAttackFinish;
      animationTimer = millis();
      println(knight.health);
      knight.clearCombos();
    }
    miss = false;
    println(knight.health);
    attackBuffer = -1;
  }
    }
  }
  void drawDamage(){
    activeKingImg = kingTakeDamage;
    animationTimer = millis();
  }
  
  void update(){
   super.update();
   if (health <= 0){
     drawDeath();
     if (deathTimer <= -1){
       deathTimer = millis();
     }
   if (deathTimer >= 1000){
     death();
   }
   }
  if (millis() - animationTimer < 1000) {
    return;
  }
   nullifyLeft();
   nullifyRight();
   nullify();
   autoAttack();
   
   displayBlocked();
   displayMiss();
  }
 
  void drawHealthBar(){
    super.drawHealthBar();
  }
  
  void nullify(){
    if (knight.combos.size() >= 1){
      if (sideBlock < 1 && knight.combos.get(0) == 1){
        nullify = true;
    }else if (sideBlock >= 1 && knight.combos.get(0) == 2){
        nullify = true;
    }
    }
  }
}

class Player extends Character{
  boolean prep, dodge;
  float roll;
  int stamina;
  float preppingTimer;
  float rollingTimer;
  float animationResetTimer;
  float staminaTimer;

  
  ArrayList<Integer> combos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  
  Player(PVector pos, int health, float attackTimer, int damage){
    super(pos, health, attackTimer, damage);
    prep = false;
    dodge = false;
    roll = millis();
    attackTimer = millis();
    stamina = 6;
    preppingTimer = -1;
    rollingTimer = -1;
    MAX_HEALTH = 10;
    activeFrames = defaultSword;
    animationResetTimer = millis();
    staminaTimer = -1;

  }

  void updateFrame() {
   super.updateFrame();
   
  }

  void clearCombos(){
    combos.clear();
  }
  
  void notEnoughStamina(){
    if (millis() - staminaTimer < 500);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill(0);
    textSize(50);
    text("Not enough \nstamina!", width/2 + width/4 + 50, width/3 + width/3);
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  void restingSword(){
    activeFrames = defaultSword;
  }
  
  void attackingAnimation(){
    activeFrames = swingSword;
    animationResetTimer = millis();
  }
  
  void swordDodge(){
    activeFrames = swordDodge;
    animationResetTimer = millis();
  }
  
  void drawDamage(){
    activeFrames = swordDamage;
    animationResetTimer = millis();
  }
  
  void animationReset(){
    if (activeFrames != defaultSword && millis() - animationResetTimer > 500){
      restingSword();
    }
  }
  
  void rolling(){
    stamina += 3;
    if (stamina > 6){
      stamina = 6;
    }
    roll = millis();
    clearCombos();
    rollingTimer = millis();
    println(roll);
    println(rollingTimer);
    println("rolling");
  }
  
  void keyPressed(){
    if (millis() - roll >= 250){
    if (key==CODED && millis() - attackTimer >= 250) {
      if (keyCode==UP) prep=true;
      if (keyCode==DOWN) {println("rolling happening");rolling();swordDodge();}
    if (prep == true) {
      if (keyCode==LEFT) combos.add(1);
      if (keyCode==RIGHT) combos.add(2);
    }
    } else if (key==CODED && millis() - attackTimer <= 500) {
    preppingTimer = millis();
  }
  attackTimer = millis();
  dodge = false;
  println("Combos: " + combos);
  }else if (millis() - roll <= 500){
    dodge = true;
    rollingTimer = millis();
  }
}

  void keyReleased(){
  if (key==CODED) {
    if (keyCode==LEFT) prep=false;
    if (keyCode==RIGHT) prep=false;
    }
}
  void drawMe(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    scale(3,6);
    if (img != null) {
        image(img, 0, 0);
    }
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  void drawDeath(){
    super.drawDeath();
  }
  
  void update(){
   super.update(); 
   displayRolling();
   displayPrepping();
   updateFrame();
   animationReset();
  }
  
  void displayRolling(){
    if (rollingTimer >= 0 && millis() - rollingTimer <= 1000){
      strokeWeight(1);
      fill(0);
      textSize(20);
      text("rolling!", width/2 + width/4 + 50, width/3 + width/3);
    }
  }
  void displayPrepping(){
    if (preppingTimer >= 0 && millis() - preppingTimer <= 1000){
      strokeWeight(1);
      fill(0);
      textSize(20);
      text("performing an \naction!", width/2 + width/4 + 50, width/3 + width/3);
    }
  }
  void drawHealthBar(){
    super.drawHealthBar();
  }
}
```

I know the rolling class is executing properly because the stamina += 3 is working as intended and I dont have the roll being set anywhere else aside from the constructor of the class and in the rolling method.

I've tried debugging by placing println at various points where the problem might have stemmed from and it all points back to here so I am a bit clueless as to how to solve the problem.